# SetForm Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::SetForm()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I'm doing form validation in jquery and using wamp server.But I'm getting these two errors 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer:: SetForm()`
and `Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::SetForm()` I added PHPMailerAutoload.php also.An even set all localhost setting in `php.ini` and also in Apache `mail function` but still it throws an error.

can anyone tell me what might be the problem here?
Help will be appreciated.
[image]

```js
<?php
 isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['select'],$_POST['time'],$_POST['message']);
 require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail -> IsSmtp();
 $mail -> SMTPDebug = 1;
 $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
 $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 $mail -> Port = 465;
 $mail -> IsHTML(true);
 $mail -> Username = "your@gmail.com";
 $mail -> Password = "123";
 $mail -> SetForm("your@gmail.com");
 $mail -> name = $name;
 $mail -> body = $message;
 $mail -> AddAddress = ($email);
 if (!$mail -> Send()) {
  echo "mail not send";
 }
 else {
  echo "Your mail successfully sent....";
 }
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" method="post" action="form.php">
  <div>
   <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></input>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="email"></input>
   <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>    
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_phone">Phone:</label>
   <input type="number" id="contact_phone" name="phone"></input>
   <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>    
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_select">Number of People</label>
   <select id="contact_select" name="select">
    <option value="">select number of people</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">Select Number of Members</span>   
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_time">Time</label>
   <select id="contact_time" name="time">
    <option value="">select Time</option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">Select Time option</span>   
  </div>     
  <div>
   <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
   <textarea id="contact_message" name="message"></textarea>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>            
  </div>     
  <div id="contact_submit">    
   <input type="submit"></input>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: The method name is `setFrom`, you hero ... has nothing to do with _forms_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: SetForm -> setFrom